# AngularUI Not Loading Correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I add angularjs and angularui to my project but it's appearing correctly. It looks like this http://postimg.org/image/vzq0uki3d/ . I don't understand why. My code is right and I'm pretty sure everything its set up correctly. The example.js file is in the root directory with the index.html file. Heres my code.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    <h4>Single toggle</h4>
    <pre>{{singleModel}}</pre>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
        Single Toggle
    </button>
    <h4>Checkbox</h4>
    <pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Radio</h4>
    <pre>{{radioModel}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ButtonsCtrl = function ($scope) {

  $scope.singleModel = 1;

  $scope.radioModel = 'Middle';

  $scope.checkModel = {
    left: false,
    middle: true,
    right: false
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with AngularUI.  However, I don't think you have the ButtonsCtrl defined properly.  You don't use it as a vary.  I think you need something like this:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ButtonsCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.singleModel = 1;

  $scope.radioModel = 'Middle';

  $scope.checkModel = {
    left: false,
    middle: true,
    right: false
  };
}]);
```

See comments about defining ButtonsCtrl in global namespace.  Working example : http://cdpn.io/HDegL

Comment: Actually, your version will work.  However it is very bad practice to define your controllers in the global scope.  Here is working demo : http://cdpn.io/HDegL

Comment: I replaced my code with the code in the link provided by both answers and it still doesn't work and I have no idea why??? Everything is the same as in codepen so there shouldn't be any reason why its not showing up with nice buttons instead of the ones from the pic I posted earlier . The example.js file is in the root directory with index.html too so everything should be in the right spot unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your debug console? Check to see if the CSS file is actually loading.

Comment: I looked at the debug console and this is the result http://postimg.org/image/dpyvd5od3/full/    I forked and exported to zip the codepen webpage so this straight from the site too

Comment: The debug console shows your problem.  The two red files did not load.  You need to check their paths in your `<head>` to make sure they are correct.

Comment: In fact, you have `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`  That is not a valid link.  Change it to `<link href="netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I changed that link and still have the problem. Also heres an image of my entire setup http://postimg.org/image/xsgzuyo1z/ because the only file I have in the folder is the example.js file and index.html file so is there something else that needs to be there?